# Is there a way to install Elixir master branch in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, elixir

Currently jenkins-ci uses kiex to handle Elixir support. Is there a way to get kiex in jenkins to install and use the elixir master branch for tests ?

If a travis yml such as this is used:

```
language: elixir
elixir: master
otp_release:
  - 17.0
sudo: false
```

The following error ensues:

```
Build system information

Build language: elixir

Build image provisioning date and time

....

Installing Elixir master

0.30s$ wget http://s3.hex.pm/builds/elixir/vmaster.zip

--2015-07-04 02:27:10--  http://s3.hex.pm/builds/elixir/vmaster.zip

Resolving s3.hex.pm (s3.hex.pm)... 54.231.112.64

Connecting to s3.hex.pm (s3.hex.pm)|54.231.112.64|:80... connected.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden

2015-07-04 02:27:10 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Comment: `kiex install master` seems to be supported - https://github.com/taylor/kiex/issues/26

Comment: You should open this as an issue on the `kiex` project - https://github.com/taylor/kiex/issues/new - I find it very unusual that `kiex` is attempting to download a compiled version via hex.pm - the source suggests that all installs are compiled on the client machine.